# Script to clean up Wine processes

Tags: wine

I sometimes have Wine in a half-dead state (Some app crashed). What is the most simple and safe way to clean up all the left over processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wine FAQ suggests this:

```
wineserver -k
```

http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-9d93db2588a3de850b0d42b1944431ac24534caa